# Most deployable way to build a web framework on IIS?

Tags: iis, deployment, web-config

So... I've never used IIS (always Apache), but I'm writing a framework now in C# (because I love C#), so I suspect it will be deployed on IIS (possibly mono/apache), and I'm trying to figure out how I should design it such that it's easy to install.

Most PHP frameworks come with an `.htaccess` file which sets up the routing, so you basically just extract the files and you're good to go. If I'm not mistaken, I can do something similar enough with `web.config`. Is that the route to go?

Or is it customary for IIS users to be expected to configure their settings when using a new framework? I'm thinking in terms of Windows-based shared hosting. What would be most compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your application's configurations will need to be setup in your web.config. You can setup the version of .NET, custom binaries, email settings, custom error pages, etc. with your web.config. It basically tells IIS how to run your application. You can also define custom settings and read them from your application.

Comment: Didn't realize that when I made changes in the IIS Manager GUI it was saving the changes to `web.config`. I get it now :) That makes it easy to deploy methinks.